# Write output file to given location using python

Tags: python, lxml

Currently my below python code is pulling XML file from DB and writing it to python files location using `eTree` library.

However, I want to write the file at another location like: `D:\MyFolder`

Please can anyone help in modifying code.

```
from lxml import etree
query = "select [file_name], [file] from [TEST].[dbo].[Files] where filing_id = 1"
results = connsql.cursor().execute(query,values).fetchall()

for r in results:
    filename = r[0]
    myXML = etree.XML(r[1])
    etree.ElementTree(myXML).write(filename + ".xml", pretty_print=True) # How to give file location here?
```

Comment: The first argument of `etree.ElementTree().write()` is your file name. [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) are pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution - using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

```
from lxml import etree
from pathlib import Path
query = "select [file_name], [file] from [TEST].[dbo].[Files] where filing_id = 1"
results = connsql.cursor().execute(query,values).fetchall()

target_dir = Path(r"D:\MyFolder")

for r in results:
    save_loc = target_dir / (r[0] + ".xml")
    myXML = etree.XML(r[1])
    etree.ElementTree(myXML).write(save_loc, pretty_print=True)
```